# com.google.api.services.Oauth2 not found

Tags: java, oauth, google-plus, single-sign-on

I'm trying to implement Google Plus login in a web application.
Currently following [this](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow) guide.

As I'm using Java on the server side, I am trying to follow the Java code snippets. My callback uri points to a servlet. Currently on step 8, I encountered my first real problem: I cannot validate the retrieved token, because Oauth2 class is not present in the [Google API client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) library.
After some googling, I found [this](https://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/), and it looked promising, but after carefully comparing the two, the included jars are exactly the same as the Google API client - neither contains the Oauth2 class.
After more searching, I found [some documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/oauth2/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/oauth2/Oauth2.html) that mentions the class I am looking for, but I am not able to find the jar containing it.

My question is: where can I find the Oauth2 class if not in the two packages mentioned above?

Comment: If it were Android, I'd say you'd have to import "Google Play Services" from your sdk>extras folder. So I guess you need another package similar to that somewhere. 
Working with Google Auth is always a pain imo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it in the Maven repository.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-oauth2